# memcache install for MAMP using wrong API version

Tags: memcached, mamp

I'm attempting to install memcache for MAMP. It seems to configure/make/install fine but I'm getting an error saying the API version is wrong:

```
[26-Oct-2012 17:40:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I am using MAMP 2.1.1 on OS X Mountain Lion.

I'm using this memcache build:
http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/2.2.7

I extracted the archive into this directory:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/memcache-2.2.7

And then ran these commands from the extracted directory:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/phpize 
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

No errors except what I noted above, which I am seeing in: 
/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I am having this same issue. were you able fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after a few hours of trying to figure this out, I was able to find the problem and fix it. I'm pretty much a huge noob when it comes to all of this stuff, but here is the best I can explain what I think I figured out:

So, when I ran first ran phpize on the module, it was configured for my system's default installation of php. I had to point php and phpize to my PATH in my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/opt/local/bin
```

Make sure to change the php version to what ever version you are running.

After adding this to your path, running `phpize -v` should return:

```
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

and running `which phpize` should return: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.3/bin/phpize`

So then it was just a matter of deleting all of the files that were installed the first time, and running through the installation process again. I unzipped the downloaded file cd into the unzipped folder and ran:
    /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.3/bin/phpize 
    ./configure
    make
    cp modules/memcache.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/

And boom done. It works!

This article helped me out a lot, even though it isn't related to memcache: http://drupal.org/node/1464236